# Polkadot and Ethereum compatiblity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, polkadot, evm

I've read that blockchains connected to the main relay chain of Polkadot can communicate with external blockchains such as Ethereum, using a bridge.

My question is:
Why would someone deploy a dapp to the Polkadot ecosystem, to Moonbeam for example, if it is compatible with the EVM nevertheless ?
Why shouldn't I just deploy to Ethereum and then communicate with Polkadot through a bridge ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why shouldn't I just deploy to Ethereum and then communicate with Polkadot through a bridge ?

- Gas fees are more expense.
- Polkadot and Moonbeam are burning money to get adoption and paying you in the form of investment / greants.